# drupal 7 warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in element_info()

Tags: php, drupal-7, draggable, roles

I have written the code with an idea of the core module named user, the role function.
my "user_admin_types" is like "user_admin_roles". If you take a brief look at "user.admin.inc" file you will understand that i have replaced my functions and variables on the basis of these:

> "user_roles"  = "user_types"
>
> "role"        = "type"
>
> "rid"         = "ut_id"
>
> "name"        = "ut_label"

Everything is that I've done is same as the Core has done but i have this warning in my page: `Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in element_info`.

I have checked every line but i couldn't find the reason and the way i can disappear it.

```
`function user_admin_types($form, $form_state) {
  $types = user_types();

  $form['types'] = array(
    '#tree' => TRUE,
  );

  $order = 0;
  foreach ($types as $ut_id => $ut_label) {
    $form['types'][$ut_id]['#type'] = (object) array(
      'ut_id'     => $ut_id,
      'ut_label'  => $ut_label,
      'ut_weight' => $order,
    );

  $form['types'][$ut_id]['#weight'] = $order;
  $form['types'][$ut_id]['weight'] = array(
    '#type'          => 'textfield',
    '#title'         => t('Weight for @title', array('@title' => $ut_label)),
    '#title_display' => 'invisible',
    '#size'          => 4,
    '#default_value' => $order,
    '#attributes'    => array('class' => array('type-weight')),
    );
    $order++;
  }

  $form['ut_label'] = array(
    '#type'          => 'textfield',
    '#title'         => t('User Type'),
    '#title_display' => 'invisible',
    '#size'          => 32,
    '#maxlength'     => 64,
  );

  $form['add'] = array(
    '#type'     => 'submit',
    '#value'    => t('Add type'),
    '#validate' => array('user_admin_type_validate'),
    '#submit'   => array('user_admin_type_submit'),
  );
  $form['actions'] = array('#type' => 'actions');
  $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
    '#type'   => 'submit',
    '#value'  => t('Save order'),
    '#submit' => array('user_admin_types_order_submit'),
  );

  return $form;
  }

/**
 * Form submit function. Update the type weights.
 */
function user_admin_types_order_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  foreach ($form_state['values']['types'] as $ut_id => $type_values) {
    $type = $form['types'][$ut_id]['#type'];
    $type->ut_weight = $type_values['weight'];
    user_type_save($type);
  }
  drupal_set_message(t('The type order have been updated.'));
}
function user_types() {
  $query = db_select('users_types', 'ut');
  $query->addTag('translatable');
  $query->fields('ut', array('ut_id', 'ut_label'));
  $query->orderBy('ut_weight');
  $query->orderBy('ut_label');
  $result = $query->execute();

  $types = array();
  foreach ($result as $key => $type) {
    switch ($type->ut_id) {
      // We only translate the built in type names
      case WEBNOVIN_CUSTOMER_UT_ID:
          $types[$type->ut_id] = t($type->ut_label);
        break;
      case WEBNOVIN_PREFERRED_CUSTOMER_UT_ID:
        $types[$type->ut_id] = t($type->ut_label);
        break;
      case WEBNOVIN_SALES_AGENT_UT_ID:
        $types[$type->ut_id] = t($type->ut_label);
        break;
      default:
        $types[$type->ut_id] = $type->ut_label;
    }
  }

  return $types;
}`
```

Comment: Can you provide an output of this code for me? `$form['types'][$ut_id]['#type'] = (object) array(` you can get some strange results when values start with integers in casting objects as arrays and weight in the array will ultimately be a integer.

Comment: @Ryank `object(stdClass)#541 (3) { ["ut_id"]=> int(1) ["ut_label"]=> string(10) "customer" ["ut_weight"]=> int(0) }` is the result

Comment: @Ryank I have a theme on this form too same as Core. Besides when i delete the part you have mentioned, the warning becomes disappeared.

Comment: Illegal offset type errors occur when you attempt to access an array index using an object or an array as the index key! In the error does it say what line number and file? as element_info is not present in the script! Just looking at user.admin.inc and can see what you are trying to do but need a little more info.

Comment: @Ryank someone answered me : "I suspect the problem is that you did a global search/replace on role/type which has changed #role into #type in your first foreach. #type is used to indicate to the FAPI what kind of element you're adding." it was true. The warning has gone

Comment: Excellent, glad you got it fixed.